# How do I know which ajax request is about to execution?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have multiple `ajax` calls in my project, which are being executed on timely basis using `timeInterval()`.

I'm showing some loading/refreshing effect using:

```
jQuery(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    //load/refresh effect start
});

jQuery(document).ajaxStop(function(){
    //load/refresh effect stop
});
```

My question is, how do I know which `ajax` call is going to execute now? I don't need to show load effect for a particular `ajax` call. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can use `ajaxStart()` and `ajaxStop()` for this purpose... they are not called for every request... so check which request it was called for does not make any sense... if you want to do something for every call then you will have to look at `ajaxSend()` and `ajaxComplete()` handlers

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Arun P Johny.

**Example:**

```
<script type="application/javascript">
$(document).ajaxSend(function( event, jqXHR, ajaxOptions ){
 console.log(ajaxOptions); //<- This will show all options of ajax ( default + passed during ajax call)
});
$.ajax({
    url: 'test.php',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data){

    }
    // ,requestNumber: 1 //<- You can pass extra parameter if require to check which ajax or can be checked using other options passed
});

$.ajax({
    url: 'test.php',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data){

    }
    // ,requestNumber: 2 //<- You can pass extra parameter if require to check which ajax or can be checked using other options passed
});
</script>
```